# How to get the current link for a menu (11ty / ejs)?

Tags: ejs, eleventy

I have a menu.json file, where is info about pages and their links:

```
{
    "Home": "./",
    "Services": "./services.html",
    "About": "./about.html",
    "Portfolio": "./portfolio.html",
    "Team": "./team.html",
    "Contact": "./contact.html"
}
```

And i have partial header.ejs, that will be included to the pages:

```
<ul
  class="main-menu"
  >
    <% for (var link in menu) { %>
      <li class="main-menu__item">
         <a
           class="main-menu__link"
           href="<%= menu[link] %>"
           ><%= link %>
         </a>
       </li>
   <% } %>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class for the current page link. What I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

In the docs for [Eleventy Supplied Data](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-eleventy-supplied/), they mention the page object which contains `page.url`. If you compare that to the link value, you can recognize when you are on a page.

Maybe something like so:

```
<ul
  class="main-menu"
  >
    <% for (var link in menu) { %>
      <li class="main-menu__item">
         <a
           class="main-menu__link
<% if(page.url === link) { %>
currentpage
<% } %>
"
           href="<%= menu[link] %>"
           ><%= link %>
         </a>
       </li>
   <% } %>
</ul>
```